# How to reference PL/SQL record type from another package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a package that declares a record type:

```sql
create or replace package schema_1.package_a as
  type r_user_type is record (
    name  varchar2(100),
    email varchar2(100)
  );
end;
```

How do I reference this record type from a package in a different schema in the same database? I have provided correct grants so that `schema_2.package_b` has `EXECUTE` privs to `schema_1.package_a`.

I have tried the following ways, and get a `PLS-00206: %TYPE must be applied to a variable, column... error` each time.

```sql
create or replace package body schema_2.package_b as
  procedure display_user_info
  is
    -- attempt 1
    r_user_info  schema_1.package_a.r_user_type%type;

    -- attempt 2
    r_user_info  schema_1.package_a.r_user_type%rowtype;

    -- attempt 3
    r_user_info_type  schema_1.package_a.r_user_type%type;
    r_user_info       r_user_info_type%type;
  
  begin
    select *
      into r_user_info
      from table(table_expression...);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

%TYPE and %ROWTYPE are only used on a data object like a table or column or cursor to abstract it into a type. r_user_type is not a table/column, but a TYPE. So, when you reference r_user_type, you are already directly referring to a TYPE, and therefore it doesn't need the %TYPE or %ROWTYPE modifiers. Just remove them and you're good.

Comment: Thank you for your response, as well as, explanation. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `%TYPE` or `%ROWTYPE`, just use the type name:

```sql
create or replace package body schema_2.package_b as
  procedure display_user_info
  is
    r_user_info  schema_1.package_a.r_user_type;
  begin
    select *
    into   r_user_info
    from   table(table_expression...);
  end;
end;
/
```

However, you also probably need a `WHERE` filter on the `SELECT` statement (or some other form of limiting rows such as `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`) otherwise, if the table expression contains more than one element then you will get an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I have a WHERE clause - left out for brevity.